Can you serialize a class instance within class method?
I have a class which has a method which performs various calculations. Prior to beginning the calculations, I want the class instance to be saved in a format where I can easily load it again. Since the actual class contains various data types, I am using dill to accomplish this. However, I was wondering if the following is possible (it seems not, but I want to better understand the reason why not): I thought to have a method which dumps the class instance to a file.
I guess the better way of doing what I want to accomplish is to, at the location where I am going to call the "get_water_frequency" method, first dump the class instance and then call that function. But it's not totally clear why I can't do it within the class.
A dummy example:
import dill

class Plant:
    def __init__(self, name, height):
        self.name = name
        self.height = height

    def get_water_frequency(self,save_path=None):

        # before doing a task, I want to save my instance
        if save_path is not None:
            self.save(path=save_path)

        if self.height>3:
            water_frequency=2
        else:
            water_frequency=3

        return water_frequency

    def save(self,path):
        with open(path, "wb") as dill_file:
            dill.dump(self, dill_file)
        return

#
my_rose = Plant('White Rose',4)
my_rose.save('C:/my_rose.dill')

with open('C:/my_rose.dill', "r") as dill_file:
    rose_from_file = dill.load(dill_file)


Running the above gives the following error upon dill.load():
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing_save.py", line 31, in <module>
    rose_from_file = dill.load(dill_file)
  File "\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py", line 297, in load
    return Unpickler(file, ignore=ignore, **kwds).load()
  File "\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py", line 452, in load
    obj = StockUnpickler.load(self)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 488: character maps to <undefined>



Works just fine when I run it on my MacOS (and change the filename).

You write the file as binary ("wb") but you read it as "r".

Ahh, thanks a lot. After switching to "rb", it works as I hoped. Thanks!

On Unix it probably doesn't make a difference, but it does on Windows because of the CRLF newlines.
